# How can you profile how long a trigger takes in OracleDB?

Tags: oracle

There are some AFTER INSERT triggers on the application I'm working on, and I'm trying to optimise them. However, I need to know what I'm doing is actually improving performance.  I'm looking in:

> SELECT * from v$SQLAREA;

But I can't find anything that relates exactly to triggers. Is there some Oracle magic that will tell me how long my triggers are taking?

Comment: v$sqlarea shows SQL statement that are executed.  It knows nothing about triggers.

Comment: I think the elapsed time includes the trigger time, does it not?

Comment: ELAPSED_TIME/EXECUTIONS give you the average time per call.

Comment: But does that include the trigger time of that SQL statement - side effects?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, but move into the trigger code.

```
declare 
  t1 timestamp; 
  t2 timestamp; 
  l_name varchar2(30); 
begin 
  t1 := systimestamp; 
  --- do whatever here that will fire the trigger
  t2 := systimestamp; 
  end loop; 
  dbms_output.put_line('Start: '||t1); 
  dbms_output.put_line('  End: '||t2); 
  dbms_output.put_line('Elapsed Seconds: '||TO_CHAR(t2-t1, 'SSSS.FF')); 
end;
```